# Logic Apps (from Azure Data Lake to Share Point)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

I need to copy csv file from Azure Data Lake Blob Container to Share Point document library.
I've tried to create Azure Logic Apps but I can't select columns from variable to create csv. Do you have an idea how to select columns or other way to copy csv file from ADL to SharePoint?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details of the array data in variable ? And what's the problem when you use the variable to create csv table ?

Comment: I don't know how to select column from variable to create csv file. I guess I should create schema in one of the block.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your array data ? And describe how do you want to select the column ? Then I can try to help you, because I can select the variable when "Create CSV table", so I'm not so clear about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I' not so clear about the details of your requirement, so I can just provide suggestions based on your description. You mentioned select columns from variable to create csv, please refer to my sample of select columns from variable(array) to create csv.

In my logic app, I have a variable which store the array like below screenshot:

[image]

If I just want to create csv with one column `name` and remove column `mail`, we can use "Select" to select the column `name` like below screenshot.

[image]

Then use "Create CSV table" to create the csv.

[image]