# ADLS Gen 2 to Sharepoint via Logicapps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to transfer files between ADLS Gen 2 storage to Sharepoint via Logic Apps, i can manage to transfer files between sharepoint and adls but struggling with the reverse way..

Comment: Does this [reference1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/) and [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672161/logic-apps-from-azure-data-lake-to-share-point) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer files from ADLS to Sharepoint through Logic Apps. Below is how you can do so.

Considering the below files in my container

[image]

Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

I'm iterating inside my container seeking the path and then sending the content from Blob storage to Sharepoint.

**RESULTS:**

[image]

You can delete the same files from the blob storage using the below connector at the end of the flow.

[image]

You can automate this flow by replacing `When a HTTP request is received` with `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)`.

[image]